# Weighted bipartite matching with constraints on degrees of vertices

Tags: algorithm, matching, graph-algorithm

I have a problem that I was able to conceptualize as following:

We have a set of *n* people. And *m* subsets representing their ethnicity like White, Hispanic, Asian etc.
Given any combination of these people, I want to check if it is a diverse group.

A diverse group is a group that satisfies several requirements, each requirement is of the form "at least *Ki* persons in the group belong to subset *Si*". Here is the tricky part, one person can only be used to satisfy one requirement. As in, you can't use him/her for multiple requirements.

An example:

Given:

At least two people from Hispanic= {a,b,c}

At least two people from Asian={a,d,e}

Is the group {a,c,d} a diverse group?

The group {a,c,d} is not diverse because you cant count *a* as Hispanic and Asian. But,
the group {a,c,d,e,f} is diverse because we have two Hispanics a and c and two Asian d and e.

### Attempt:

This is an instance of the Assignment problem. The jobs are the ethnicity and we can put as many ethnicity as the requirement dictate. For example, if we need two Hispanic, then we put two Hispanic jobs. However there only some people are able to do a particular job.

This is my attempt so far:

I will construct a bipartite graph with the set of people **P** on one hand and the set of ethnicity on the other **S**. We will put an edge between a person **p_i** and an ethnicity **S_i** if he/she belongs to the ethnicity.
Now, we will modify the graph, for every ethnicity **S_i** duplicate it **k_i** times (**S_{i,1}, S_{i,2}, ... , S_{i,k_i}**). And add new edges accordingly. Find the maximum matching M of this graph.

Now, merge the **S_{i,j}** s into one **S_i** and there you have a diverse group. However, a maximum matching is only a possible solution to to the problem. And my problem is a decision problem, I want to check if a given group is a solution or not.

Comment: Do you mean _at least Ki persons in the group (can) belong to Si different subsets_?

Comment: @angelatlarge, I mean Ki persons belong to the set Si.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici, His father is Asian and his mother is White, that happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an instance of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem, usually described in terms of assigning people to jobs, so in your case the job is "sit there and look white" or "sit there and look hispanic". Only some people are qualified to do any particular job, and they can only do one job at a time.

Normally the assignment algorithm minimizes a cost, but you can just use cost 0/cost 1 for "is in the right ethnic group" or not.

One means of solving this is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm. This is often presented for the case in which there are exactly as many workers as jobs, but you can always invent dummy jobs or dummy workers, with all costs associated with dummies the same cost, so that optimizing the problem with dummies reproduces exactly the relative order of costs you would get if you ignored assignments to dummies, and so the optimum with dummies is the same choice, after ignoring dummies, as the optimum without.

Comment: I don't understand how it is an instance of the assignment problem. Since my problem asks: given a group of people and list of requirements, is the group diverse or not. So I'm not trying to find a diverse group, rather check if a group is diverse. Plus in the assignment problem, every one job is linked to one person, however in my problem you can have one job(ethnicity) linked to multiple people. Can you please explain. Thanks.

Comment: In your question you give an example of a group that is diverse "because we have two Hispanics a and c and two Whites d and e". The idea is to use the assignment problem to find the information to put in such a justifying statement. If you can find such info the group is diverse, if you can't it is not. In this example you would create two jobs requiring Hispanics and two jobs requiring Whites and then see if you can solve that assignment problem with the group in question.

Comment: @modowella, Can you please look at my attempt. I added it to the question. Thanks

Comment: Your description of setting up the assignment problem and asking it to find a maximum matching seems OK. Once you have a maximum matching you work out whether or not the group is diverse - what the decision is - by looking at whether the maximum matching in fact fulfills the requirement. If the requirement was for two Hispanics and two Whites, you look to see if the matching recovered really does link two different whites with the two jobs requiring whites, and two different Hispanics with the jobs requiring Hispanics.